# Как добавить элемент в значение словаря Python?

Tags: python, словарь

У меня есть словарь например

```
d = {'Машина': 'car', 'Мячик': 'ball'}
```

и я хочу добавить в ключ "Машина" еще одно значение через генератор словарей, чтоб получилось:

```
'Машина': 'car', 'machine'
```

Comment: Чтобы так сделать, значение должно быть списком, кортежем или еще каким другим множеством. А так просто присвоить второе значение ключу нельзя

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё довольно просто. Тебе нужно вместо одного значения по ключу хранить список.
В этом случае есть две ситуации. Когда мы должны только создать этот список и, когда можем уже добавить в него значение.

Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
if dict.get(key, False) is False:  # если в словаре нет такого ключа
    dict[key] = [value]  # добавляем его и помещает туда список с одним значением
else:  # если такой ключ уже есть
    dict[key].uppend(value)  # добавляем значение в конец списка
```

.get - метод словаря, который возвращает значение по ключу, а если его нет, то False (по умолчанию None и это можно даже не указывать, здесь привёл просто для наглядности).

Эту конструкцию можно поместить в цикл, где как раз будут перебираться все значения.

Answer (score 1):

Выше чел написал:

```
if dict.get(key, False) is False:  # если в словаре нет такого ключа
    dict[key] = [value]  # добавляем его и помещает туда список с одним значением
else:  # если такой ключ уже есть
    dict[key].uppend(value)  # добавляем значение в конец списка
```

Я проверил, работает код, если внести некоторые правки. Зарегистрировался специально, чтобы об этом написать, но репутации не хватает для того, чтобы прокомментировать его ответ, поэтому пишу свой ответ.

Во-первых, key и value должны быть строками, то есть, в кавычках.
Во-вторых, команда, добавляющая элемент в список, append, а не uppend.

```
dict = {}
if dict.get('key', False) is False:
    dict['key'] = ['value']
else:
    dict['key'].append('value')
print(dict) # {'key': ['value']}
if dict.get('key', False) is False:
    dict['key'] = ['value']
else:
    dict['key'].append('value2')
print(dict) # {'key': ['value', 'value2']}
```

Но можно элегантнее проверять наличие ключа в словаре, поэтому я бы предложил такой вариант:

```
dict = {}
if 'key' not in dict:  # если в словаре нет такого ключа
    dict['key'] = ['value']  # добавляем его и помещает туда список с одним значением
else:  # если такой ключ уже есть
    dict['key'].append('value')  # добавляем значение в конец списка
print(dict) # {'key': ['value']}
if 'key' not in dict:  # если в словаре нет такого ключа
    dict['key'] = ['value']  # добавляем его и помещает туда список с одним значением
else:  # если такой ключ уже есть
    dict['key'].append('value2')  # добавляем значение в конец списка
print(dict)  # {'key': ['value', 'value2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Структура словаря: {ключ: значение}
2. Ключ в словаре всегда д/б уникален.
3. Если будет добавляться повторяющийся ключ, то старый затерется.
4. В значение можете что-угодно кинуть:

```
dict_temp = {}
dict2_temp = {1: 123, 2: '321'}
dict_temp['key_1'] = 'значение 1'
dict_temp['key_2'] = ['значение 1', 'значение 2']
dict_temp['key_3'] = (['значение 1', 'значение 2'], dict2_temp)
dict_temp['key_4'] = [key_data for key_data in dict2_temp.keys()]
```

Теперь посмотрим что насобирали через:

```
for key, val in dict_temp.items():
    print( key, ':', val)
```

Выведет:

```
key_1 : значение 1
key_2 : ['значение 1', 'значение 2']
key_3 : (['значение 1', 'значение 2'], {1: 123, 2: '321'})
key_4 : [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Павел, переменная dict зарезервирована переменная в питоне и лучше не использовать такие имена, а заменить ее на my_dict или подобное.

Также выложу цикл который у меня получился на базе показанного кода, может кому то пригодится.
Цикл делает из списка строк словарь, потом проверяет если такой ключ, если ДА, то просто добавляет к уже существующему значение, новое значение, если нет создает новую пару *ключ : значение*.

```
inp = ['+71234567890 Сергей', '+71234567810 Сергей', '+51234567890 Михаил', '+72134567890 Николай']
my_dict = {}
for i in inp:
    value, key = i.split()
    print(f'k={key} и v={value} {type(key), type(value)}')
    ##if dict.get(key, False) is False:
    if key not in my_dict:
        my_dict[key] = [value]
    else:
        my_dict[key].append(value)
print(my_dict)
```

Всем удачи в программировании.